# TwigExtension added to Craft don’t work in emails

Tags: craft3, plugin-craftcommerce2, modules, twigextension

I added `tomodomo/twig-pluralize-extension` to my project composer, loaded with a custom module like that :

```
if (Craft::$app->request->getIsSiteRequest()) {
    // Add in our Twig extension
    $pluralize = new \Tomodomo\Twig\Pluralize;
    Craft::$app->view->registerTwigExtension($pluralize);
}
```

I use this to pluralize some string in my templates and email templates. When I check the url to my email template, everything work fine but the email didn’t send out because of "unknown function pluralize".

I have another custom module (to handle something else in my emails) and this part work fine.

Do I need to register/declare TwigExtensions with another method to get them work in emails ?

Note:

1. The only error related to my emails in the logs is about pluralize
   function missing.
2. Everything work fine if I don’t use `|pluralize`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace my `if` condition by

```
if ( Craft::$app->request->getIsSiteRequest() || Craft::$app->getRequest()->getIsCpRequest() ) {
```

Thanks to Luke Holder for pushing in the right direction!

Answer (score 1):

All you should need to do is remove this condition check:

```
if (Craft::$app->request->getIsSiteRequest()) {
```

You are only registering the twig extension for front end (site) requests, but emails can be triggered both on a cart complete front end (site) requests AND a back-end (CP) order status changes.

Comment: May I use a double condition check ? Like so :

`if (Craft::$app->request->getIsSiteRequest() || Craft::$app->getRequest()->getIsCpRequest()) {`

The email using `|pluralize` is sent from my other custom module, not from a Order Status Change.